# Is there a script that will suggest (hkl) indices based on distances in an electron diffraction pattern for a known crystal structure?

Tags: crystal-structure, python, crystallography, cif, diffraction

I am looking for a script (preferably in Python) that will suggest (hkl) indices based on distances in an electron diffraction pattern. The crystal structure is known,i.e. I have the CIF file and know the space group.  This has already been done in Fortran, just wanted to know if it was out there in Python!  [I was able to find a FORTRAN version](https://www.phase-trans.msm.cam.ac.uk/map/crystal/programs/crystal-b.html).

Comment: +1 But I am curious about why you are looking for a python version if the fortran version works?

Comment: Take a look at this package: [https://github.com/Hekstra-Lab/reciprocalspaceship](https://github.com/Hekstra-Lab/reciprocalspaceship).

Comment: @ShoubhikRMaiti To add further python code and integrate with new functionalities!

Comment: Anya, was the suggestion in the comment by Camps, useful at all?

Comment: @Camps Thanks! It's relevant. 1) Possibly the MTZ file stores experimental data and there is a function to find (hkl) indices based on the data.  2) The CIF parser seems useful in extracting information from CIF files in different formats.

Comment: @NikeDattani Thanks for checking back.  Pointers to python libraries are helpful.  Pointers to functions within the library would be even more helpful, with easy understanding of input/output.  I believe the forum conversations will eventually become that specific and easy to search for new users of these libraries :)

Comment: This question has been closed as it seems to be abandoned (OP has not returned for 5 months). It can be reopened if someone wants to add an answer or the OP addresses questions/suggestions in the comments.